# How to make a batch file which installs Network Driver automatically

Tags: batch-file, nsis

I am making an installer using the NSIS tool.

It's first time that I use NSIS and batch file script, so there are many difficulties.

The most important issue to solve is that the network driver must be installed automatically when the installation is completed.

So my idea is making a batch file to install network driver, and execute it by NSIS script.

The manual installation process is in below picture:
[image]

So my question is: Is it possible to make this process by using batch script?
And if it is: How could I get to last process in batch file? is it registry or something?

Comment: Why do you need a batch file? Why can't  you do it through NSIS instead?

Comment: I agree with you, but I tried examples like drvsetup in NSIS, but I don't understand exact way to apply it in NSIS.

https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Driver_installation_and_update
This is the link that I searched.

Do you know the way of it? By using this way, could you install inf?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the driver, you might be able to perform a .inf install:

```
Section
InitPluginsDir
SetOutPath $PluginsDir
File "mydriver*.*"

System::Call 'SETUPAPI::InstallHinfSection(p0,p0,ts,i0)' 'DefaultInstall 132 $PluginsDir\mydriver.inf'

SetOutPath $InstDir
SectionEnd
```

If you want to install a 64-bit driver with a 32-bit installer you might have to `ExecWait '"$sysdir\..\sysnative\rundll32.exe" SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 $PluginsDir\mydriver.inf` instead.

Comment: Another alternative is dpinst32.exe/dpinst64.exe or calling UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices or DiInstallDriver.